# get the number of similar items by year for each item

Tags: mysql, sql

Please take a look at this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f182e/2):

I have this query to get the percentage difference of each item's price against the average price of their own category:

```
SELECT name, product.category, ((price - avg_price)/avg_price)*100 as price_difference
FROM product
JOIN (
  SELECT category, AVG(price) as avg_price
  FROM product
  GROUP BY category
) t
ON t.category = product.category
```

Now I want to take a step further to add another query to count the number of products in the same category by year

Original table:

```
ID  name    category      year
1     A     Outdoor       2010
2     B     Doll          2009
3     C     Doll          2009
4     D     Outdoor       2010
5     E     Brainteaser   2010
6     F     Brainteaser   2009
7     G     Brainteaser   2009
8     H     Brainteaser   2009
```

The outcome should be like this:

```
name CATEGORY      DIFFERENCE   similar_products_of_the_same_year
A   Outdoor             -72%              2         
B   Doll                 29%              2
C   Doll                -29%              2
D   Outdoor               9%              2
E   Brainteaser         -88%              1
F   Brainteaser         134%              3
G   Brainteaser          65%              3
H   Brainteaser         -47%              3
```

I can only make a specific query like the following but I need to get the records for each product.

```
SELECT COUNT(year) AS similar_items_of_the_year from `product` where year in (
  SELECT year
  FROM product
  where name = "A"
)
```

Would anyone please show me how to get that outcome?

Comment: Might be an idea to reference previous discussion on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.name
     , p.year
     , p.category
     , ((p.price - avg_price)/avg_price)*100 price_difference
     , ttl
  FROM product p
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT category
            , AVG(price) avg_price
         FROM product
        GROUP 
           BY category
     ) t
    ON t.category = p.category
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT category,year, COUNT(*) ttl FROM product GROUP BY category,year ) n
    ON n.year = p.year 
   AND n.category = p.category;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f182e/14

If my result differs from yours, I *think* that's because I don't understand whether or not you consider a row as being similar to itself. If you do, just subtract 1 from ttl.